# Phonegap Battery cycle count

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap, battery

I would like to know the battery cycle count on my Phonegap app.
But I can't find a way to have it. Is it possible with Cordova/Phonegap or should I use native code for each platform ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the [cordova-plugin-battery-status](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-battery-status/) provides that information, so you'd need to either track down another third-party plugin which does this, or write your own (yes in native code).

Comment: Oh, I don't know how to do this. But thanks anyway ;) I'll find a solution.